# How would one write a function to take two values and then print and assign a new value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to write a program that you take any two (or more) numbers (x and y, lets call them) of one's choice, rational or irrational, infinite or finite, and lines up each digit one against the same digits in order of the other number(s) and then uses those digits as input values. I would like the (three, or more) output values to be x, y, and n, where n is the number assigned for those specific values of x and y at that digit (so at output, x, y, and n would be sequences, but at input x and y would be continuous numbers that the program reads as twin sequences). I know absolutely nothing about programming, but this seemed like a simple program to me. If it is not, I deeply apologize. Similarly if I am not allowed to ask for help writing a full program. If I need to pay one of you to ask for this, I can. If I need to delete this, I am willing.

I know absolutely nothing about programming, but I would like to write it in excel. I am willing to do the busy work to build it myself, but I just do not know where to start.

Comment: Maybe throw your question at ChatGPT and start there.

Comment: Checkout [this website I found](https://www.google.com). I'm not kidding when I say it's been SUPER helpful in a variety of learning journeys I've taken. Also way better than asking strangers for guidance. Good luck.

Comment: Have you seen the [tour] and [ask] already?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, consider taking the tour. Have a browse of the tags for your question, too (excel, in this case), and check out the kinds of questions that get the kinds of response that you want. Use a [markdown generator to add tables for clarity](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#).

If you are seeking something like:

| X Input | X Output |  | Calculation |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345678 | 75318642 |  | X | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |  |
|  |  |  | Y | 7 | 5 | 3 | 1 | 8 | 6 | 4 | 2 |  |
|  |  |  | N | 8 | 7 | 6 | 5 | 13 | 12 | 11 | 10 |  |

You may be able to just use Excel. Split up your problem into a few parts:

- To split X and Y into characters, you just need something like:
  https://exceljet.net/formulas/split-text-string-to-character-array
- If you want to output N as a single cell, consider CONCAT(range of cells taken by N output). There are a handful of ways to work out the last column used, but that depends upon how you handle two-digit cells.
- Each digit column for N is rudimentary - it's just a SUM(). Regarding two-digit sums, though, your solution depends upon how you handle those. If you want to add a fourth row (output M?), then you can just run the character-splitting functions on those, also. If you want to treat this as literally "ten" and carry a digit ... then the calculation becomes more difficult. In that case, I suggest splitting out the digits of X/Y *in reverse* (ones place on the left), and then doing the calculation left-to-right. That means all values carried upward end up in a single cell at the far right, and CONCAT() is straightforward.

Along with the tutorials already mentioned in the comments, I think this should give you some ideas on how to proceed.